# Typescript generates properties which not exists

Tags: node.js, typescript

Am using package both packages [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) for JavaScript and [@types/config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/config) for TypeScript. When im trying to build my script is crashing with error:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

My code:

```
const _dbconfig:any = config.get('database');
```

The generated piese of code:

```
const _dbconfig = config_1.default.get('database');
```

Why tsc generates *default* property and how i can prevent it?

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Comment: The error says that `config` is not defined. Can you check that `config` is properly imported and initialized?  And also generated ts code in `dist` will have its own file maps after build/transpilation which does not always match with `src/` folder code

Comment: @SagarChilukuri my code is correct. When i bulding the code - everything is correct. Just when tsc generated javascript - it adds default property. When i remove it myself - is running correct. I think problem with configuration of TSC.

Comment: You might want to remove `any` as that might obscure errors you might otherwise have gotten.

Comment: @Kapcash Yes. please write an answer, i will mark it